# What's the difference between It's like to ~ vs It's like ~ing?

Tags: expressions

What is the difference between using to ~ and verbing after "it's like".
For example,

1. What it's like to leave a company you started
2. What it's like leaving a company you started

Answer (score 1):

In this case, very little, if any. Maybe the first one puts more emphasis on the result and the second on the process, but that would be really splitting hairs.