# Difference between the two sentences '... like to swim' and '... like swimming'?

Tags: meaning

1. He likes to swim.
2. He likes swimming.

What is the nuance hiding behind these two?

Comment: also [Difference between "like to go ..." and "like going..."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/594208/) and [What's the difference between It's like to ~ vs It's like ~ing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/422620/) possibly the question with the best answer [“I like to do (be) something” vs “I like doing (being) something”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21498/)

Comment: "He likes swimming" could refer to watching the sport of swimming (or otherwise following it).